# flutter - from text to textField

Tags: flutter, class

i am fairly new to flutter, can anyone help me? pls

This code make that what written in the TextField() class, once the RawMaterialButton() is pressed , transform it into text inside the container() class.

When I press the other RawMaterialButton() the code returns from the container() class to the textField() class.

I would like once back to the textField class, i would like that once back to the textField class, the text previously written is written in the TextField

How can I do? Thank you :)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(mainApp());

class mainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: chat(),
    );
  }
}

class chat extends StatefulWidget {
  const chat({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _chatState createState() => _chatState();
}

class _chatState extends State<chat> {
  bool changeClass = false;
  String? text;
  changeClassValue(String? newText) {
    setState(() {
      changeClass = !changeClass;
      text = newText;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: changeClass
          ? container(
              text: text ?? "",
              changeClassValue: changeClassValue,
            )
          : textField(
              changeClassValue: changeClassValue,
            ),
    );
  }
}

class textField extends StatefulWidget {
  textField({Key? key, required this.changeClassValue}) : super(key: key);

  ValueChanged<String> changeClassValue;

  @override
  _textFieldState createState() => _textFieldState();
}

class _textFieldState extends State<textField> {
  final textController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 300.0,
            height: 60.0,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: TextField(
              controller: textController,
            ),
          ),
          RawMaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {
              widget.changeClassValue(textController.text);
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.send),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class container extends StatefulWidget {
  container({Key? key, required this.text, required this.changeClassValue})
      : super(key: key);

  String text;
  ValueChanged<String> changeClassValue;

  @override
  _containerState createState() => _containerState();
}

class _containerState extends State<container> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 300.0,
            height: 60.0,
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Text(widget.text),
          ),
          RawMaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {
              widget.changeClassValue(widget.text);
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.edit),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

hope someone can help me.

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we get into this, definitely make sure your class names start with a capital letter. Names like `Container` and `TextField` are already defined in Flutter so you'll probably need different names for these widgets.

The two widgets don't have to be `StatefulWidgets` but `StatelessWidgets` will make it easier to work with. The `Chat` widget should however be the only one with state here. This widget should have the `TextEditingController` in its state and pass it along to the `textField` to use.

The `container` should get its `text` property from this same `TextEditingController`.

Both widgets should also get a callback function, such as a `VoidCallback` to toggle between which one to show.

Here's an example:

```dart
class Chat extends StatefulWidget {
  const Chat({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChatState createState() => _ChatState();
}

class _ChatState extends State<Chat> {
  bool changeClass = false;
  final textController = TextEditingController();

  toggleClass() {
    setState(() {
      changeClass = !changeClass;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: changeClass
          ? ChatContainer(
              text: textController.text,
              toggleClass: toggleClass,
            )
          : ChatTextField(
              textController: textController,
              toggleClass: toggleClass,
            ),
    );
  }
}

class ChatTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController textController;
  final VoidCallback toggleClass;

  ChatTextField({
    Key? key,
    required this.textController,
    required this.toggleClass,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 300.0,
            height: 60.0,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: TextField(
              controller: textController,
            ),
          ),
          RawMaterialButton(
            onPressed: toggleClass,
            child: Icon(Icons.send),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChatContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final VoidCallback toggleClass;

  ChatContainer({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.toggleClass,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 300.0,
            height: 60.0,
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Text(text),
          ),
          RawMaterialButton(
            onPressed: toggleClass,
            child: Icon(Icons.edit),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```